# What methods can I use to block adult content?

Tags: firewall

I'm looking for something along the lines [of K-9](http://www1.k9webprotection.com/) for my phone.  Does such a thing exist?

**My goal:** to have all adult content blocked.

I would like to know if this is possible and if it is, how to do it.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are offtopic, but if you specifically outline your needs we can provide objective answers about apps that address them.

Comment: @matt : better?

Comment: Yes, but "adult content" is subjective ... you may get better answers if you specify what types, or if you specify that the app should allow you to control what types or allow/block certain sites, etc.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a rooted phone, you can always edit your hosts file to block known adult sites.

Trying to block all sites is an exercise in futility, unless you opt for a slight reversal of logic and use white-listing wherein only allowed websites are allowed to be connected to and all others are blocked. As of now, I'm not aware of any app on Android that offers this functionality.

There are other avenues for adult content - the Android Market is one of them and blocking that seems counter-productive for a smartphone.

Also take a look @ [DroidWall](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.googlecode.droidwall.free) - an app that only allows certain apps to access the Net.

**UPDATE:**Trend Micro's paid app [Mobile Security](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.trendmicro.tmmssuite) seems to have parental controls, although I can't vouch for the app's efficacy. The user reviews don't paint a very comforting picture but a 30 day trial is available so you can test the app out yourself.

Comment: One note, the Android Market now has ratings settings to control what app you see.  The user would just have to have someone else set a PIN, or set one and forget it.  But it does block out things non-adult, i.e. Google+ app is considered High Maturity.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't block content, but [X3Watch](https://market.android.com/details?id=cc.updatable.doubleagent) monitors what websites you visit.  If you use that in conjunction with DroidWall as suggested by Sparx, or use an App Protector to block/limit other apps, that may help.

**Update:**  [Covenant Eyes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.covenanteyes.androidservice&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5jb3ZlbmFudGV5ZXMuYW5kcm9pZHNlcnZpY2UiXQ..) now has an app now available in the Market.  As with X3Watch, it doesn't block sites (though it may in the future) but reports what websites you visit.    It is officially a beta version, but seems to work well.  The app itself is free, but usage requires a Covenant Eyes account - which also covers usage of any programs on the PC or Mac.

Answer (score 3):

It may be worth contacting your carrier. I know vodafone UK, for example, offers some sort of parental control. Though this wouldn't monitor access over wifi.

Answer (score 3):

T mobile has some sort of optional content filter also. I know that it only works when you are browsing over 3g/4g/edge, not wifi. I don't know how well it works though, as the only experience I had with it was it being turned on in error and me having to call to get it turned back off.

Comment: AT&T has this as well, but I don't remember how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[K9 Webprotection](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bluecoat.k9.android) is out for Android.
*Seems like it does not work for some devices, though, as it's based on Firefox.*
This can always be combined it with an app locker to block the default Chrome browser.