# How can I stop the Android Market from showing bad/naughty apps?

Tags: google-play-store

I am using Honeycomb with Xoom, it's very annoying to see all the bad naughty apps all over the market, for example in the category "Libraries and Demos". Although we can ignore them and not download, I do not think those things should be there, because children also use the OS.

Is is normal for the Market to have all these (e.g. Korean Sexy girls, etc.)? Or is my Xoom breached? I also have an HTC Desire, and these apps do not appear on that device.

Answer (score 21):

The Android Market has an included content Filter, which should filter most of these Apps. Ratings are

- Everyone
- Low Maturity
- Medium Maturity
- High maturity

## Android 2.3 and lower

1. Open Android Market.
2. Press Menu and touch Settings.
3. Touch ‘Select filtering level’ and choose your desired setting.
4. To lock the settings, touch the lock icon and enter a PIN code.

## Android 3.0 and higher

1. Open Android Market.
2. Press Menu on the upper right corner.
3. Touch ‘App Content Filter’ and choose your desired setting.
4. To lock the settings, touch the lock icon and enter a PIN code.

[Source](https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1075738)

Comment: Thanks, for your answers, but I was under the impression that..maturity means regarding usage, more advanced. Not the kind of maturity here. And the "so called apps" are still there with low maturity. Thanks.

Comment: Android or not: You may want to have a look at this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6190/what-methods-can-i-use-to-block-adult-content But this question is more about general blocking of adult content. If you give a kid a smartphone with internet access, the nudity market apps will be your least problem. The internet is full of bad things...

Comment: @Androidornot if you read the definition of High Maturity on the Market help page it says "Applications in this category may focus on or include frequent instances of sexual and suggestive content; graphic violence; social features; simulated gambling; and strong alcohol, tobacco and drug references. Applications may collect user location data for the purpose of sharing or publishing with the user’s consent." so it is to do with content filtering rather than advanced usage.

Comment: @Flow sorry looks like we posted at the same time with similar answers and linked to the same Market Help page!

Comment: Thanks.. My opinion here is that such content should not be included in the Android market, having their own website is ok. Thanks for all your help. "Open" is good, until malicious people ruin it.

Answer (score 5):

Apps in the Market should be pre-rated for their "maturity level". If you go into the Market app and then into its Settings, you should have a Content Filtering option.

Taking the tick out of "High Maturity" should remove all "adult-only" apps from your view of the Market.

See this Google Help article for more info: [Application Content Ratings](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/bin/answer.py?answer=1075738)